# Return partial view with large data

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have partial view that returns large volume data.. something like below
    return PartialView("MyPartialView", model);

The partial view is getting returned as ActionResult. Ajax Post request is used for calling the Action Method. The code is giving following error while trying to bind the returned data to kendo drop down. Any solution

Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151993/2210329

Comment: Can this be handled somehow in the code itself ? How would I be able to give jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue; .The content type I have is contentType: "text/html",